# How to retrieve the current user in OpenERP module

Tags: odoo

I'm developing an OpenERP 7 module and I need to add a field that logs the user who created each record. How do I retrieve the current user object?

Answer (score 2):

this kind of field is already available in openerp, as create_uid and write_uid.

Answer (score 1):

In OpenERP Python code, functions generally take `cr`, the database pointer, and `uid`, the user id, as arguments. If all you need is the id of the current `res.users` object (for instance, to write into the one2many field), you can use `uid` as is. If you need to access the object (to see fields, etc.), something like:

```
current_user = self.pool.get('res.users').browse(cr, uid, uid, context=context)
```

should work.